# $E(X)$ given $f_{X,Y}$

Tags: probability

I'm given a certain $f_{X,Y}$ joint density function and I'm asked to find $E(X)$. I know you can find the marginal distribution $f_X$ and then easily compute $E(X)$. However:

**Question:** I want to know if there's a smart way to go directly from the joint density to the expectation. Is there a specific theorem that could be applied in this case?

Thanks for helping! :D

Comment: $$E(X)=\iint xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$

Comment: See the first comment on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/344128/102009). Your $Z$ would just be $g(X,Y)=X$.

Comment: Is there a special theorem?  Just the definition of expectation. $$\begin{align} \mathsf E(X) & = \int x f_X(x)\operatorname d x \\ ~ & = \int x \int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y \operatorname d x \\ ~ & = \iint x f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
E(X)=\int xf_X(x)dx\\=\int x\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx\\=\int\int xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx
$$